# Python to find directory, find file, delete file based upon args/user input

Tags: python, search, automation, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm fairly new to Python. I'm using Python 3.7 and need to write an automated application that can find a directory, multiple files within that directory and delete them based upon user input args. I want to call it like:

```
removefiles.py -d DIR -f M10
```

or

```
removefiles.py -d DIR -f M{10...20}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import fnmatch

# Get a list of all files in directory
for rootDir, subdirs, filenames in os.walk('/dir/$USER/dir/{REGION}'):
# Find the files that matches the given pattern
for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'ZONE' 'ID'):
    else:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'ID'):
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(rootDir, filename))
    except OSError:
        print("Error while deleting file")

def main():
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("region",
                    help="Specify the region to delete from",
                    metavar="REGION")
parser.add_argument("id",
                    help="Specify the ID, e.g., M61",
                    metavar="ID")
parser.add_argument("-z",
                    help="Specify the zone to delete",
                    metavar="ZONE")
```

as indicated, I need to be able to find either specified files or files in a range. The files do not end with M10 (or any other number) but the names contain that. Please help.

Comment: please add the code

Comment: Sorry, like I said fairly new to Python. I dont have the code yet because I honestly dont know the best way to start going about it. I just know how it needs to be called, file structures, paths.

Comment: add the code of removefiles.py